# I want workaround for not using global variable in the code

Tags: python, function, global-variables

Below is my sample and I want a workaround for not using the global variable inside the function.

```
Legend = '''
<style>
table {
    font-family: Times New Roman, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style> '''
for i in ts:
    Legend+= '<th>' + i + '</th>'
Legend += '''</tr>'''

def get_data_legend(value,name,sym=None):
    global Legend
    L1 = []
    for i in value:
       L1.append('{:,.0f}'.format(i))
    Legend += '''<tr><th>'''+name+'''</th>'''
    for i in gt:
        if sym is not None:
             Legend+= '<td>' + sym + str(i)  + '</td>'
        else:
             Legend += '<td>' + ' ' + str(i)  + '</td>'
    Legend += '''</tr>'''

get_data_legend(update_datapoints,'Update metrics')
get_bus_metrics(update_address,'Update address')
Legend += '''</tr></table><br><br>'''
```

I am using the global variable inside the function that is not good to use or worst thing to use. I am looking for a workaround so that I don 't need to used global variable inside the function. I am new to the python can someone please try to help me on this.

Comment: Make your function take an argument `legend` and have it return a value?

Comment: @timgeb Sorry I am new to the python, didn't get can you please elaborate or provide me a small example of that

Comment: I think what @timgeb is saying is that the usual way to avoid it is by passing the data as a named argument to the function. This case is a little trickier because the function modifies the value, so it needs to `return` the variable's final value as a result.

Comment: @timgeb apology to buy you again, I define above function in this way
**def get_data_legend(value,name,Legend,sym=None)** should it return Legend + get_data_legend ?

Comment: @martineau Littlebit confused here, what it should actually return

Comment: Just add a `return Legend` line at the end of the function so it will return whatever its final value ended-up being. If you edit your question and provide a runnable sample, we can show you what we mean.

Comment: @martineau I already tried that, in this case its not adding any o/p to the html table **Legend** when I am calling this function _get_data_legend(update_datapoints,Legend,'Update metrics')_

Comment: Don't froget to remove the `global Legend` statement. You're also going to need to do something like this when you call the function: `Legend = get_data_legend(update_datapoints, Legend, 'Update metrics')`. The problem with that however, is `Legend` will no longer have its initial value, so results will likely be wrong if the function is called again with it as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
>>> something = 'something'
>>> def bad():
...:    global something
...:    something += ' bad'
...:
>>> bad()
>>> something
>>> 'something bad'
```

You should have

```
>>> def good(something):
...:    something += ' good'
...:    return something
...:
>>> something = good('something')
>>> something
>>> 'something good'
```

Comment: That works, Thanks for the info really appreciate that.

Comment: @martineau note that the original version and your edit of this answer are only  equivalent if we assume immutable objects (like strings in OP's case) are passed to `good` as `+=` performs mutations whenever it can.

Comment: timgeb: I know that...and it's just such a case here and in the OP's question.

Comment: @martineau right, but the concept explained here does not hinge on the data type of the argument, so I figured we should have at least a comment that mentions the behavior of `+=` in case a future reader of this question wants to adapt the code to work with, say, lists.

Comment: It's yer answer... `;¬)`